# lisp Cons cell diagram for the list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

This is my trying code.

```
(defun f (lst)
  (cond ((null lst) nil)
        ((listp (first lst))
         nil
         (f (car lst)))
        (t (cons (first lst)
                 (list (f (cdr lst)))))))
(f '(a (b) c))
==> (A (B NIL))
```

My goal is `(f '(a (b) c))` should return `(a . ((b . nil) . (c . nil)))`.

Or `(f '(a b))` should return `(a . (b . nil))`.

This mean is process cons cell.

How do I fix it?

Another thing I wonder process symbol.

To process the symbol I use try `(format t " . ")` and recursively to print list,

But it's not going well.

Where should I start modify?

Comment: `(a . ((b . nil) . (c . nil)))` is the same as `(a (b) c)` (just visualized differently, like 4 quarters and a dollar are the same amount of money). Do you want it to return a string `"(a . ((b . nil) . (c . nil)))"`?

Comment: I want Not string. like this (a . ((b . nil) . (c . nil)))

Comment: To have your function **return** `(a . ((b . nil) . (c . nil)))` that doesn't use the standard formatting `(a (b) c)` would be impossible. You can either return a string representation or you can print the string representation to the screen (not returning it).

Comment: I appreciate for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## What you said

To **return** `(a . ((b . nil) . (c . nil)))` when the argument is `(a (b) c)` you don't need to do anything - these to are the **same** already (use [`identity`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_identi.htm) :-).

Please take a look at the manual:

- [The Consing Dot](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_cc.htm)
- [Left-Parenthesis](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_da.htm)
- [Printing Lists and Conses](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/22_ace.htm)

Specifically:

> Although the two expressions below are equivalent, and the reader accepts either one and produces the same cons, the printer always prints such a cons in the second form:
>
> ```
> (a . (b . ((c . (d . nil)) . (e . nil))))
> (a b (c d) e)
> ```

## What you probably meant

If you need to construct a **string** `"(a . ((b . nil) . (c . nil)))"`, you would need to work:

```
(defun cons-cell-diagram-string (x)
  (if (consp x)
      (format nil "(~A . ~A)"
              (cons-cell-diagram-string (car x))
              (cons-cell-diagram-string (cdr x)))
      (princ-to-string x)))
(cons-cell-diagram-string '(a (b) c))
==> "(A . ((B . NIL) . (C . NIL)))"
```

## What you might also have meant

Another possible interpretation of the task is to return a list but insert dots as strings:

```
(defun cons-cell-diagram-list (x &optional (consing-dot "."))
  (if (consp x)
      (list (cons-cell-diagram-list (car x) consing-dot)
            consing-dot
            (cons-cell-diagram-list (cdr x) consing-dot))
      x))
(cons-cell-diagram-list '(a (b) c))
==> (A "." ((B "." NIL) "." (C "." NIL)))
(cons-cell-diagram-list '(a (b) c) '|.|)
==> (A |.| ((B |.| NIL) |.| (C |.| NIL)))
(cons-cell-diagram-list '(a (b) c) '#\.)
==> (A #\. ((B #\. NIL) #\. (C #\. NIL)))
```

## PS

Please note that I took liberty to format your code according to the commonly accepted Lisp coding standards.

It becomes immediately obvious that you have a superfluous `nil` (on a separate line) in the `listp` clause.

You might want to use Emacs to edit your code.